# How do I output HTML in a Blade template without chancing an XSS attack?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

If a variable contains the following:

```
$straddr = "1 elm street<br>Unit 4<br><i>City Unknown</i>Alabama";
```

and I want to include that variable in a Blade template, I could do something like this:

```
<td>{{ $straddr }}</td>
```

but this will show the HTML tags.

However, [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data) says

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`

It seems that using the `{!! $variable !!}` syntax in the blade file could be quite risky.  Or is it in this case?

Is it overly risky to not escape the data that is coming from the database?

Comment: It depends on the use case and how you feel about the data stored in your database.  It's great for blogs and pages with dynamic content created by a wysiwyg. If it's only created by logged in users (such as a blog or content only created by employees), then no worries. If it's content generated by anyone, then definitely risky and probably should not have html tags anyway.

Comment: Consider something whitelist-driven that uses a full HTML parser, like http://htmlpurifier.org/. There's a Laravel package for it: https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier

Answer (score 3):

In comments, we have determined that this HTML is in fact being generated by you in your controller method. So the real question is, why are you going to all this trouble just to subvert the MVC paradigm?

Assuming you have a `User` model with properties `address_1`, `address_2`, `address_3`, `city`, `state`, and `zip_code`, this is what you need to do.

```html
<td>
@if($user->address_1)
    {{ $user->address_1 }}<br/>
    @if($user->address_2) {{ $user->address_2 }}<br/>@endif
    @if($user->address_3) {{ $user->address_3 }}<br/>@endif
@else
    <i>{{ __("Street address unknown") }}</i><br/>
@endif
@if($user->city || $user->state)
    {{ $user->city ?? "?" }}, {{ $user->state ?? "?" }}
@else
    <i>City and state unknown</i>
@endif&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $this->zip_code ?? "" }}
</td>
```

The rest of the code you provided is doing data validation, which should absolutely not be done at this stage in the data's life cycle. Your data should be validated at point of entry into your application, whether that's user input, CSV import, or whatever. You should not be having to capitalize city names, figure out if your address is > 3 characters long, or wonder if you have an abbreviation or a full name for a state at the point of displaying it.

Comment: I think Blade will still force the <br> tag tp be typed out and not rendered.

Comment: yes.  then use {!! !!} .  Your first comment let me to that conclusion.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The docs for `strip_tags` have a big red warning that states **"This function should not be used to try to prevent XSS attacks."** `<strong onmouseover="alert('foo')">` will still execute its JS after a `strip_tags` run if `<strong>` is a permissible tag.

Comment: @ceejayoz good point. May have to rethink this answer

Comment: I agree.  so how can the objective be acheived?  The objective being i have three address fields:  [address_1], [address_2], [address_3], then [city], [state], [zip] fields / columns.  I retrieve those from a DB, and I want to show on the screen as
the address on seperate lines on the screen.  how can you do that without scraping the <br> tag with strip_tags.  is the only answer to do that in the blade template with if conditions? (don't want a blank line when address_2 and address_3 are blank values.

Comment: a php need:  a form of strip tags function what will insure that there are no attributes for the tag.  or perhaps the function would allow classes, but that would be bad for jquery as functions run for classes of objects.  so perhaps, the strip tags function would unsure that only naked accepted tags were returned.  e.g., if <strong> were a permissable tag, then the new php strip tags function would allow only <strong> and </strong> to be rendered, but any event attributes would still be stripped; in your example, the onmouseover event and action would still be stripped.  is there such a func?

Comment: @RobertBryanDavis See my comment on your question itself; https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier handles this correctly. You set a whitelist of tags *and* attributes, and it uses a full HTML parser to do it. As I said elsewhere, though, since you have the underlying data parts, I'd do the HTML generation in Blade using those parts instead of passing Blade a variable with HTML.

Comment: Agree with @ceejayoz that you should just be doing this with conditional statements. Your question didn't mention that this variable was constructed by you, I assumed it was user entry.

Comment: Question:

if this is returned from my component as a variable in a blade template:
return  "<i>Individual</i>";  is that subject to an xss attack?  it is not coming from a database.  it is simply a string with an italics tag.  could someone inject a javascript method into it somehow?

Comment: Your blade template should be handling formatting. Your controller should not be concerned with how the data it's returning is presented, and should not be dealing with HTML tags at all. I think this whole question is just a big XY problem, the real question is what data do you have and where does it come from? If you're the one adding the HTML then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've updated my answer to get rid of the `strip_tags` recommendation; thanks for pointing out the problems with it.

Comment: @miken32 Much appreciated, have an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for your comments miken32

Comment: @RobertBryanDavis no problem, hope it was helpful.

Comment: indeed you and @cejayoz were most helpful.  I am thankful for ya'lls persistence.

Answer (score 2):

Any data that is provided from users, even if stored in the database in-between, should be considered unsafe by default. In this particular case, you are running a risk of a stored XSS.

You should ensure your data is probably

1. escaped (`htmlspecialchars`, `strip_tags`, etc.) and
2. validated (can you enforce a pattern, character limits (only A-Z or numbers), or length limitation?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that is it.  {{  }} used in Blade component or template will always render the tags as html entitities.  So the key is, as miken32 said above, is simply use the strip_tags on the string before you return it, then use the {!! !!} to render the ,say, 
 tag as actual break tag and not as an html entity.

Thank you miken and speckulatius.

---

Okay, i am convinced the strip_tags is not a good idea.  So here is the question again, and perhaps an answer.  One of the answers was just edit the Blade Template so you put the 
 tag directly in the template, in stead of risking it being in the database.  But I think it can still be done on the back end.  Here is the functon I am using to render my address of a person in the data table.

```
public function getFullAddressFhAttribute(){
        $a1 = (!is_null($this->address_1) && strlen(trim($this->address_1))>3) ? ucWordsSpace(trim($this->address_1),'addr') : '';
        $a2 = (!is_null($this->address_2) && strlen(trim($this->address_2))>3) ? ucWordsSpace(trim($this->address_2),'addr') : '';
        $a3 = (!is_null($this->address_3) && strlen(trim($this->address_3))>3) ? ucWordsSpace(trim($this->address_3),'addr') : '';
        $c =  (!is_null($this->city) && strlen(trim($this->city))>2) ? Str::title(trim($this->city)) : '';
        $s = (!is_null($this->state) && strlen(trim($this->state))>1) ? trim($this->state) : '';
        $s = (strlen($s)==2) ? strtoupper($s) : Str::title($s);
        $z = (!is_null($this->zip_code) && strlen(trim($this->zip_code))>4) ? formatzip($this->zip_code) : '' ;

        $address = (strlen($a1)>3) ? $a1 : '';
        $address .= (strlen($address)>3 && strlen($a2)>3) ? "<br>$a2" : '';
        $address .= (strlen($address)>3 && strlen($a3)>3) ? "<br>$a3" : '';
        $address = (strlen($address)>3) ? $address . "<br>" : "<i>Street Addr Unknown</i><br>";
        if(strlen($c.$s)==0)
            $address .= "<i>City,State Unknown</i>";
        else{
            $address .= (strlen($c)>2) ? "$c," : "?, ";
            $address .= (strlen($s)>1) ? " $s" : " ?";
        }
        $address .= (strlen($z)>4) ? "  $z" : '';

        $safeElements = ["<br>", "<b>", "<i>"];
        return strip_tags($address, $safeElements);
    }
```

I think the above function would be safer if it was rewritten to strip_tags of the first 7 variables, like so:

```
 public function getFullAddressFhAttribute(){
        $a1 = (!is_null($this->address_1) && strlen(trim($this->address_1))>3) ? ucWordsSpace(trim($this->address_1),'addr') : '';
        $a2 = (!is_null($this->address_2) && strlen(trim($this->address_2))>3) ? ucWordsSpace(trim($this->address_2),'addr') : '';
        $a3 = (!is_null($this->address_3) && strlen(trim($this->address_3))>3) ? ucWordsSpace(trim($this->address_3),'addr') : '';
        $c =  (!is_null($this->city) && strlen(trim($this->city))>2) ? Str::title(trim($this->city)) : '';
        $s = (!is_null($this->state) && strlen(trim($this->state))>1) ? trim($this->state) : '';
        $s = (strlen($s)==2) ? strtoupper($s) : Str::title($s);
        $z = (!is_null($this->zip_code) && strlen(trim($this->zip_code))>4) ? formatzip($this->zip_code) : '' ;

        $a1 = strip_tags($a1);
        $a2 = strip_tags($a2);
        $a3 = strip_tags($a3);
        $c = strip_tags($c);
        $s = strip_tags($s);
        $z = strip_tags($z);
        
        $address = (strlen($a1)>3) ? $a1 : '';
        $address .= (strlen($address)>3 && strlen($a2)>3) ? "<br>$a2" : '';
        $address .= (strlen($address)>3 && strlen($a3)>3) ? "<br>$a3" : '';
        $address = (strlen($address)>3) ? $address . "<br>" : "<i>Street Addr Unknown</i><br>";
        if(strlen($c.$s)==0)
            $address .= "<i>City,State Unknown</i>";
        else{
            $address .= (strlen($c)>2) ? "$c," : "?, ";
            $address .= (strlen($s)>1) ? " $s" : " ?";
        }
        $address .= (strlen($z)>4) ? "  $z" : '';

        $safeElements = ["<br>", "<b>", "<i>"];
        return strip_tags($address, $safeElements);
    }
```

So strip all the tags out before you put the safe ones back end.

Comment: Don't use `strip_tags`. Read the red boxes on https://www.php.net/strip_tags. It does **not protect from some forms of XSS.**

Comment: I agree.  so how can the objective be acheived?  The objective being i have three address fields:  [address_1], [address_2], [address_3], then [city], [state], [zip] fields / columns.  I retrieve those from a DB, and I want to show on the screen as
the address on seperate lines on the screen.  how can you do that without scraping the <br> tag with strip_tags.  is the only answer to do that in the blade template with if conditions? (don't want a blank line when address_2 and address_3 are blank values.

Comment: If you have the underlying address parts, yes, I'd do it in the Blade template itself.

Comment: never easy is it.

Comment: a php need:  a form of strip tags function what will insure that there are no attributes for the tag.  or perhaps the function would allow classes, but that would be bad for jquery as functions run for classes of objects.  so perhaps, the strip tags function would unsure that only naked accepted tags were returned.  e.g., if <strong> were a permissable tag, then the new php strip tags function would allow only <strong> and </strong> to be rendered, but any event attributes would still be stripped; in your example, the onmouseover event and action would still be stripped.  is there such a func?

Comment: Re: your edit, of course it's possible to do the string construction in the controller... but this sort of templating is what Blade is *for*. I don't think your code is safe, either; try putting `<b onmouseover="alert('foo');">` in address_1, and `</b>` in zip, then mouse over the resulting address.

Comment: Are you saying you're storing this HTML in the database? That's not a good idea at all. HTML is a method of displaying the data; storage should be agnostic.

Comment: No. no html in the database.  i am taking address fields from the db and putting <br> between the fields to display them. so the question is, do i put the <br>'s in on the back end or on the template?  I am using laravel and models so I like the idea of putting it in the model [function getFullAddressFhAttribute()] lwhich returns the full address on separate lines for a table presentation.  So I think I am going to put the few tags into the variable in the model then return it to the template that way displayed like {!! $user->fulladdress_fh() !!}

Comment: @RobertBryanDavis Don't do that. Render it, piece by piece, in a Blade template. You could even put `public function getFullAddressAttribute() { return view('path.to.your.address.blade.template')->render(); }` on the model to be able to do `$this->full_address` and have it render the Blade template wherever you want.

Comment: i am using livewire, so it is rendering the blade template which resides in a livewire component.

the model retrieves address fields, strips all the tags out of each variable that holds the individual address fields, then pieces the variables together adding the <br> tag in, then returning the value.  $a1 = strip_tags(trim([address fld])).  same with $a2, $a3, $city, $state, $zip.  so every field is assigned to a variable, cleaned up, then pieced back together with <br> tags, then returned.  so nothing but numbers and letters coming from db fields, then tags added and returned .  Not good?

Comment: Again, `strip_tags` is not the right approach. I've given you several options; at this point it seems you're not reading my proposed approaches.

Comment: i am curious.  how can an xss attack be carried out if i have a function on the back end that simply returns a variable like the following:  

$x = "<i>hello world</i>"; return $x;

  and in the blade template you have

 <div>{!! $x !!}</div>

can you demonstrate how someone could attack that?  The above function does not touch a database or any value in a table of a database.  the function just is a string typed in literally surrounded by an html tag.  No strip_tags() calls in the function at all.

and i am being serious.  Is this attackable, and if so, how?

Comment: There's no XSS attack possible in that specific scenario, but it's not the scenario you've described in your question. It's also a contrived scenario, and one you'd be better off just putting the `<i>hello world</i>` in the Blade template itself; there's no reason to have a variable involved.

Comment: what if the 'hello world' text came from a database?  assume there is one record in the table for this example.  I have left some code out obviously, but assume that $result[0] contains the value 'hello world'.   $result = ('select distinct `text` from `exampletable` where LOWER(`text`) LIKE "%hello%"');  $x = "<i>" . strip_tags($result[0]) . "</i>"; return $x;  then in the blade component {!! $x !!}.  and say that someone had somehow put unwanted javascript code in the value of `text`.  could that code make it  thru strip_tags() function in tact?

Comment: @RobertBryanDavis My last attempt at this: `strip_tags` does **not protect you from XSS**. The docs have red warnings saying exactly that. If `$result[0]` contains user-submitted data you haven't personally created or verified, you risk an XSS attack. I've previously given you examples of input that would evade `strip_tags` using `onmouseover`.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with it.  My goal was to get specific examples of how the attack could be carried out.  What specific dangerous items could make it thru the strip_tags and how.  E.g. I also put data thru a home made filter that strips special characters  as well.  I have heard the warnings but have not seen how it is done.  No need to answer this.  You’ve done more than enough.

Comment: It pays to read the warnings.  My apologies.  Again thank you for your persistence.

Comment: You know, it still seems to me that if you  $x = strip_tags($var) [notice you have no allowed tags here in this strip_tags() function call], then you add the tags you want back in, ($y = “<i>” . $x . “</i>”) and then render that in blade with {!! $y !!}, then you cannot be attacked.  Any tags that were in the database … say the string in the field is “<i onmouseover=maliciousattach()’>hello world</i>“.  $x=Strip_tags([fld]) takes the <i> tag out, then you put it back in, then render it.

Comment: Above you suggest - ‘ try putting <b onmouseover="alert('foo');"> in address_1</b>…’.  Okay, that string is assigned to the var $x.  $x = “<b onmouseover=‘alert(‘foo’)>1 maple street</b>”.  $y = strip_tags($x).  $z = “<b>” . $y . </b>”.  In blade {!! $z !!}.  I believe that is the example i gave before your last attempt above.    Since you take all tags out with the strip_tags() call, there are no allowed tags, it seems that the alert(‘foo’) could not make it to the html that is rendered.  Agreed?  I hope you make it to this comment.

Comment: Again, in that scenario, just do `<b>{{ $y }}</b>` or just plain old `<b>1 maple street</b>` in the Blade template. You're overcomplicating it for no good reason with no benefit.

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz.